# raft: committed entry may be lost?

Tags: raft

What happens when leader crashes before all followers updates the commit index?

For example, node A, B, C forms the cluster:

- only A and B alive and A is leader
- A replicates an entry (let's say it's entry1) to B and get successful result from B
- A commits entry1, and crashes before it send out the heartbeat message to B (which would results in B updates its commit index)
- C online now

My questions is:

- would C be elected as new leader? If so, then entry1 is lost? Moreover, if A re-joins later, its data would be inconsistent with others?

I know the raft spec said:

> Raft uses a simpler approach where it guarantees that all the
>   committed entries from previous terms are present on each new leader
>   from the moment of its election, without the need to transfer those
>   entries to the leader.

But here entry1 may be not considered as committed entry? because B has not get the confirm from old leader (heartbeat from leader). So C get chances to be new leader?

- if B becomes new leader, then how it should deal with the entry1?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's important to note that an entry is considered committed once it's *stored* on a majority of servers in the cluster (there are technically some caveats to this but for this conversation we should assume this is the case) and not when a node receives a commit messages from the leader. If a commit message were required to consider an entry committed then every commit would require two round-trips - one for replication and one for commitment - and commit indexes would have to be persisted.

Instead, in your scenario, when `A` crashes and `C` recovers the Raft election algorithm will ensure that `C` cannot be elected leader and so `C` cannot drop the committed entry. Only `B` can be elected leader since it has the most up-to-date log. If `C` tries to get elected leader, it will receive only a rejected vote from `B` since `B`'s log is more up-to-date than `C`'s (it has the committed entry). Thus, what you'll see in practice is `B` will eventually be elected and will commit all entries from its prior term, at which time that entry will still be committed. Even if `B` were then to crash and `A` were to recover, `A` would still have a more up-to-date log than `C` and so it would again be elected leader.

*When* (not if) `B` becomes the leader, it will *first* ensure entries from the prior term are stored on a majority of servers before committing any entry from its current term. Typically this is done by committing a no-op entry at the beginning of the new leader's term. Essentially, the new leader commits a no-op entry, and once that entry is stored on a majority of servers it increments its commit index and sends the new commit index to all followers. So, that entry will not be lost. The new leader will ensure it is committed.

The caveats to considering an entry stored on a majority of the cluster to be committed are described in both the Raft paper and disseration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am still confused about the 5.4.1 chapter. It said "Raft uses the voting process to prevent a candidate from
winning an election unless its log contains all committed
entries.", but then it turns to define "up-to-date" targeted at the last entry (even the entry is no way to be confirmed already replicated on most nodes). The later definition covers more entries then the previous one. Why not only state the "up-to-date" definition as the election restriction?

Comment: In my case, if I changed the cluster to 5 nodes, and A crashes after A manages to replicate entry1 to B only, then which the rest node will become new leader? only B is qualified? because it has entry1 but C/D/E has not? But here entry1 has not yet replicated to most nodes (only A and B have entry1), then entry1 should not be considered as committed entry?

Comment: In that scenario, if this is a 5 node cluster then any node can be elected. The quorum is what enforces commitment. Because the entry hasn't been stored on a majority of servers it's not committed. Since it's only stored on 2/5 nodes, regardless of which other node starts an election it can receive successful votes from a majority (3/5) of the cluster, so any node can win an election. If the entry were stored on a majority of servers then the majority requirement of elections would ensure that entry is present in any new leader's log.

Comment: That is, if entry1 is only stored on two servers then any of the three other servers can be elected from votes entirely discounting the two servers on which entry1 is stored, and that's fine since that entry's not considered committed. In that case, if a leader without entry1 is elected it will essentially remove that entry from the cluster. If a leader with entry1 is elected then entry1 will end up being committed. This is where sessions become useful. When sessions are implemented, you can ensure an entry is applied to the state machine exactly once even if it's resubmitted by a client.

Comment: Thanks! I get correct understanding now. I thought the log entry may be lost until the commit index updated from all (at least majority) followers, but it's not. In fact, if the log entry is actually replicated to a majority of servers, then it's persistent; otherwise, it may be lost.

Comment: Sorry to ping 8 years later, but the "log entry being replicated to a majority of servers" is not sufficient for being persistent. ONLY once a leader will have replicated an entry from its OWN CURRENT term, then previous entries can be considered persistent (globally commited). At this point, the leader will itself apply the commited entry to its state machine, and inform followers that they can commit the entry (and apply it to their replicated state machine)

Answer (score 1):

Previous accepted answers says that

> *an entry is considered committed once it's **stored** on a majority of servers" [...] there are technically some caveats*

However, the caveat is very strong, and should not be ignored unless you are willing to sacrifice the assurance of all replicas being equals.

Please see the paper "***In Search of an Understandable Consensus Algorithm***" (https://raft.github.io/raft.pdf), **Figure 8 , situation (c -> d)**;

In the above situation, the "yellow" log has been **replicated** on a majority of servers, nevertheless, it can be overrided in situation (d) by the "blue". At the end of (c), it CANNOT be considered globally-committed.

This can happens because "*being stored on a majority of servers*" is not sufficient for being considered committed.

**ONLY** when a leaders has stored ("replicated") a log entry of **ITS OWN TERM** on a majority of servers, then this entry and ALL previous ones can be considered durably persistent [1].

Then the leader will commit it to its state machine, and ask followers to do so.

[1] : Any preemptively elected new leader at this point would also do the same than the preempted leader, because only a leader already having replicated **THIS** log entry would obtain a majority of election vote)

**-----8<-----8<-----8<-----8<**

Paraphrasing  OP's description, the following event could happen,
very similar to the Figure 8 of the aforementioned Raft paper.

> **OP's:** For example, node A, B, C forms the cluster.

OK, let's say A-B-C were all three on term 1, and were only containing once entry in their logs : a GREEN entry at index=1/term=1.

```
[A] : [GREEN term=1]
[B] : [GREEN term=1]
[C] : [GREEN term=1]
```

Then, let's say A is elected leader (term=2), is proposing a YELLOW entry at index=2/term=2.
Only A has the entry, but A has a network disruption before sending the replication on B and C.

```
[A] : [GREEN term=1][YELLOW term=2] // leader at term=2, then network-disrupted
[B] : [GREEN term=1]
[C] : [GREEN term=1]
```

Then, let's say C is elected new leader (votes from C and B) on term=3, and is proposing a BLUE entry at index=2/term=3.
Only C has the entry, but C also has a network disruption before sending the replication on A and B.

```
[A] : [GREEN term=1][YELLOW term=2] // disconnected from network
[B] : [GREEN term=1]
[C] : [GREEN term=1][BLUE term=3] // leader at term=3
```

*yes, the network switch between them is in a very bad shape.*

Them, let's say network's problem of A is no more, and A is elected leader again (votes from A and B) for term=4.

We are in this situation :

```
[A] : [GREEN term=1][YELLOW term=2] // leader at term=4
[B] : [GREEN term=1]
[C] : [GREEN term=1][BLUE term=3] // disconnected from network
```

> **OP's:** Only A and B alive and A is leader

We are now in the situation described by OP's, very similar to Figure (8) state (b) of the Raft paper.

> **OP's:** : A replicates an entry (let's say it's [YELLOW term=2]) to B and get successful result from B

Similar to Figure (8) state (c), we are now in this situation :

```
[A] : [GREEN term=1][YELLOW term=2] // leader at term=4
[B] : [GREEN term=1][YELLOW term=2]
[C] : [GREEN term=1][BLUE term=3] // disconnected from network
```

> **OP's:** : A commits entry1, and crashes before it send out the heartbeat message to B (which would results in B updates its commit index)

No It **CANNOT** commit, because A is leader-elected at term=4.
To commit [YELLOW term=2], A must replicate a entry of ITS OWN TERM (term=4) on a majority of server.

It could either replicate a new further next log entry, or generate a synthetic no-op entry, but in any case, only if this new entry is at ITS OWN LEADER TERM, once being replicated on a majority of servers, then it would be considered globally committed.

"be considered globally committed" means than once A (being leader, and SUPER IMPORTANT : being leader at term=4) would get confirmation of B that the entry at term=4 is replicated on B (**of it's OWN TERM**), then :

- A would commit it locally, apply it to the state machine, and would be able to truthfully notify the client/request of the commit.
- A would also message B to tell it than B can also commit/apply to the state machine.

The "globally" of the "be considered globally committed" here means that, if a new leader would be preemptively elected, it would also commit/apply this term=4 :

- BECAUSE only a leader already having this term=4 entry would be eligible to be voted leader at the majority.
- BECAUSE the majority would already have the log entry at term=4
- BECAUSE *NO* other majority would have at this point a "greater" log entry at term=5 (which could "win/sabotage" over the election) BECAUSE NO term=5 entry CANNOT yet exists, BECAUSE the preempted leader was "replicating an entry of **ITS OWN TERM**", and due to all others rules, at this point, it means than no other entry could have a greater term.

> **OP's:** : C online now. Would C be elected as new leader? If so, then entry1 is lost? Moreover, if A re-joins later, its data would be inconsistent with others?

Barring the "needed" thing I wrote above (commiting an entry of ITS OWN TERM), then C could be elected as leader (at term=5), B would still vote for C (because C has [BLUE term=3] which is greater than's B's [YELLOW term=2]).

Then C once elected leader would make A and B both delete [YELLOW term=2] from their logs. And then make them replicate [BLUE term=3] instead for index=2.

```
[A] : [GREEN term=1][BLUE term=3]
[B] : [GREEN term=1][BLUE term=3]
[C] : [GREEN term=1][BLUE term=3] // leader at term=5
```

Which should be fine because the entry was NOT committed (neither locally on the leader, nor globally).

This is the Figure (8), situation (d) of the Raft paper.

**CONCLUSION**

Upon normal operation, when a leader propose ("AppendEntries") a log entry, only one round-trip is necessary to achieve "globally commited" status. It means than as soon as a majority of servers replicate the log entry, then the LEADER can in parallel (in any order) :

- notify the requester/client of the entry being committed
- and locally-commit it (especially apply it to the state machine)
- and notify the followers than the can also commit/apply.

The above holds only if the leader is proposing an entry of ITS OWN TERM.

If the leader has (after a re-election) an entry from a PREVIOUS term in its log (no matter if this old entry was proposed by itself on a previous term, or another previous leader), more than ONE round trips could be necessary before achieving persistence/globally-committed :

- ONE round trip to replicate either a no-op (or a real entry) on ITS OWN TERM, which could get a temporary refusal if followers don't yet have the old entry
- very probably further round trips to replicate the "old entry(ies) of previous term(s)")
- Then again on round trip to replicate the entry of its own term

Comment: Yes, thank you for further explanation. I have reviewed the raft paper these days and confirmed two things: 1. Quorum is based on log freshness, so as long as a log is recorded on most nodes, it is persistent. 2. To ensure the safety of the first point, the leader is restricted to replicating only the log entries under the current term, of course, it will sync all previous logs and make them aligned in all nodes by the way through this process.